# How to enable anonymous access without prompting for User credentials SharePoint O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I just created our first SharePoint site on O365. I would like to give access to anyone in our organization. Here is what i did so far

1. I went to admin.sharepoint.com and shared the sure with "anyone".
2. I added our SharePoint site to the Trusted list, on User Authentication settings, tried with both anonymous and Automatic logon.
3. I asked another user to test this site, it is still prompting for a Microsoft account.

Any idea what else I should do in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user245321

There are two things going on here:

1. In SharePoint online there is no way to permit *carte blanche* `Anonymous Access`.  But given the nature of your question, I don't think you are looking for a way to permit every person who finds your SharePoint URL on the Internet to be able to access it.
   Users will be periodically prompted for their credentials.  Upon
   successful authentication their browser will be issued a token that
   will expire after a set period of time and circumstances.
   The token's lifetime and
   frequency of prompting for credentials can be configured in Azure AD
   Conditional Access policy and can be configured based on a number of
   factors, such as user sign-in frequency, device identity, device type, etc.
   This
   **[link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime)** is particularly instructive and you should carefully read.
   It also talks about browser session persistence of the
   authentication token and other factors.
2. SharePoint Online uses **[claims-based authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/claims-based-identity-in-sharepoint)**.  SharePoint Online does not have a claim called or aliased as `Anyone` or `Anonymous Access` or something similar.  (See Image 1 below).  On-prem SharePoint had the 'Everyone' claim, which *could* include external users, depending on your configuration.  In SharePoint Online, as of 2018 you can achieve what I believe you are looking to do by using the `Everyone Except External Users` claim when assigning permissions.  (See Image 2 below)  I suggest that you only grant this group `read only` access, then dole out `Edit` and `Full Access` permissions as needed.

*If this answer helped answer your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.*

**Image 1**

[image: Image 1]

**Image 2**

[image: Image 2]

Comment: When I go to Sharepoint admin center, I got the option for Sharing the site. Which pops out a side pane with External Sharing option Where there is an option to Share with Anyone "Users can share files and folders using links that dont require sign-in" .Even if i choose that, everyone is prompted for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

@user24321

Please make sure that while sharing particular file you select "Anyone with the link" option as shown in below screen.

[image]